# Pass a Jenkins environment variable as a parameter to a python script

Tags: python, jenkins

An environment variable in Jenkins the "workspace" gives me the absolute path of my directory.

I am executing the followings in `"Execute Windows batch command"` in Jenkins:

```
echo workspace = %WORKSPACE%
python ReportGenerator.py -i XXX.json -s XXX.xml -t XXX.xlsx -d ${workspace} -a XXX
```

and I get:

```
13:53:52 C:\XX\XX\XX\XXX>echo workspace = C:/Project/Jenkins/YYY/XXX/XXX/XXX
13:53:52 workspace = C:/Project/Jenkins/YYY/XXX/XXX/XXX
13:53:52 ...
13:48:14 C:\XX\XX\XX\XXX>python ReportGenerator.py -i MyJasonFile.json -s MyXMLFile.xml -t MyTemplate.xlsx -d ${workspace} -a MyProject
```

As you can see ${workspace} doesn't show the value.

How can I path the Jenkins environment variable as a parameter?

Comment: Why don't you use `%WORKSPACE%` directly? `-d %WORKSPACE%`

Comment: it works but in the end how can I change the slash to backslash in this?  15:23:40 C:/Project/Jenkins/XX/XX/XX/XXX\MyTemplate.xlsx

Comment: Did you try `%WORKSPACE%\MyTemplate.xlsx`?